# Excel VBA add-in, is Worksheet_SelectionChange possible?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an add-in that creates a report on a file, the report has a pivot table like this:

[image]

The above is now sorted on the leftmost column. To make it easier for the user I want to add a Worksheet_SelectionChange event code that if I click on a cell with "Kolli" or "Vikt" in this range visible in the image sort the table on this column.

The sorting is not the issue, but can a add-in file notice selection change?
I would need something like a ACTIVEsheet_SelectionChange, and then read the Target so that it's the correct workbook, sheet and range.
Is that even possible? Or do I need to somehow write the code in the "target" workbook worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. Put the next declaration on top of the add-in `ThisWorkbook` code module (in the declarations area):

```
Public WithEvents appEvHandler As Application
```

2. Put in `Workbook_Open` event the next code, to activate the event handler:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set appEvHandler = Application 'this code line can be placed in any standard event, when need to activate the `appEvHandler` events
End Sub
```

3. Copy this new event code in `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub appEvHandler_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   If Sh.Parent.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        MsgBox Sh.Parent.Name & " workbook, sheet " & Sh.Name & " changed selection to " & Target.Address & "..."
    Else
       Debug.Print "Selection changed in this workbook..."
   End If
End Sub
```

You can also filter the sheet (name) where the event to do something, on a similar mechanism.

I could also suggest the specific event code, but I could not understand what "I click on a cell with "Kolli" or "Vikt" in this range visible" does mean. No rows headers, I cannot understand which range to be the one triggering what you need... I mean to restrict the range where the event to be used. Is that row part of the table header? Anyhow, this part should be easy to handle, I think.

Comment: This seems to work!! Thank you! About "Kolli" and "Vikt". it's the lowest row that has a blue background. So it's the pivot table column header

Comment: @Andreas Glad I could help! So, it is good to restrict the event range to be handled for a specific workbook, sheet and that column header range...

Comment: Yes.. The issue is I can't restrict it to a workbook since the workbook is generated from SAP and the user can name it whatever he/she likes. But I have restricted it to sheet name since I'm in control of that. And the layout of the sheet. So B3 must have value xxx and B4 must be yyy and so on. It's not bulletproof but odds are low that someone would create a sheet that looks the same and it's not my macro that did it.

Comment: @Andreas Yes. You can also try better identifying the sheet according to some markers. Something like keeping a pivot table, a specific string in "A1" or wherever you need...

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for a code to sort a pivot table on column header when you click on it this is the code I use now thanks to FaneDuru.

```
Private Sub appEvHandler_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Parent.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        If Sh.Name = "Resultat" And Sh.Range("B3").Value = "Plockare" And Sh.Range("B4").Value = "Snitt" And Sh.Range("B5").Value = "Per timme" And Sh.Range("A11").Value = "Namn" And Sh.Range("B11").Value = "Plockare" Then
            If Target.Row = 11 Then
                If Target.Column > 2 And Target.Column <= Sh.Cells(4, 2).End(xlToRight).Column Then
                     On Error Resume Next
                     Sh.PivotTables("Pivottabell1").PivotFields("Kvittering av").AutoSort xlDescending, Target.Value, Sh.PivotTables("Pivottabell1").PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(Target.Column - 2), 1
                     On Error GoTo 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The Pivot table is placed in cell B11, that is why `target.column -2` is correct for me.
If yours is in A, then you probably want `target.column -1`

And the header is on row 11, that is why the code only reacts to target.row = 11